# Как прочитать этот код в C?

Tags: c++, c

Что это? Как прочитать этот код?

```
sfc_ecode(*load_rom)(void*, sfc_rom_info_t*);
```

Comment: Указатель на функцию с 2 параметрами соответствующих типов и возвращающую тип `sfc_ecode`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Переменная `load_rom` объявлена как указатель на функцию, которая принимает 2 аргумента (указатель на `void` и указатель на `sfc_rom_info_t`) и возвращает `sfc_ecode`.